# Handling objects from a C library in python code

Tags: python, c++, cython, porting

I would like to implement a C / C++ library from a `.dll` file into a Python script to control a piece of i/o equipment called [ClipX by HBM](https://www.hbm.com/en/7077/clipx-precise-industrial-signal-conditioner/) (in case anyone needs help with this in the future).

The manufacturer gives an example C implementation, and an example C++ implementation.  In the C example, the Connect() function returns some pointer, which is used in subsequent read/write functions.  In the C++ example, a ClipX class is used to establish the connection, and read/write functions are methods in that class.  I've simplified the code for the purposes of this question.

Basically, I want to `connect()` to the device, and at some later point `read()` from it.  From what I've read, it seems like Cython would be a good way to wrap `connect()` and `read()` as separate functions, and import them as a module into Python.  My questions are:

1. For the C implementation, would I be able to pass MHandle pointer back to Python, after connecting, for later use (i.e. calling the read function)?  Would the pointer even have any meaning, being used later in a different function call?
2. For the C++ implementation, could the dev object be passed to the Python code, to be later passed back for a `Read()`? Can you do that with arbitrary objects?

I am a mechanical engineer, sorry if this is gibberish or wildly uninformed. Any guidance is very much appreciated.

C Code:

```
/*From .h file*/
----------------------------------------------------
struct sClipX {
void *obj;
};

typedef struct sClipX * MHandle;
ClipX_API MHandle __stdcall Connect(const char *);
----------------------------------------------------
/*End .h file*/

int main()
{
    const char * IP = "172.21.104.76";
    MHandle m=Connect(IP);
    Read(m, 0x4428);
}
```

C++ Code:

```
int main(){
    ClipX  dev = ClipX();
    dev.Connect("172.21.104.76");
    dev.Read(0x4428);
```

Comment: you should try python C Foreign Function Interface  [link](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Please give the URL of the device you are hacking

Comment: [HBM ClipX](https://www.hbm.com/en/7077/clipx-precise-industrial-signal-conditioner/)

Comment: Please don't comment your question, but do [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61379853/edit) it

Comment: Sorry, I have added it now

Answer (score 1):

C++ functions are callable from C if you declare them as  `extern "C"`. This is related to [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

The Python interpreter can be extended with C functions. Read carefully the [*Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter*](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/) chapter.

Be careful about C++ exceptions. You don't want them to cross the Python interpreter code. So any `extern "C"`  C++ function called from Python should handle and catch [exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions) raised by internal routines.

At last, be careful about memory management and garbage collection. P.Wilson old paper on [*Uniprocessor garbage collection techniques*](https://3e8.org/pub/pdf-t1/gcsurvey.pdf) is relevant, at least for terminology and insights. Or read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/). Python uses a [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) scheme and handles specially [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference). Be careful about [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference).

Be of course aware of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) in Python. Roughly speaking, you cannot have several threads doing Python things without precautions.

[Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) of device-related data would also be a concern, but you probably don't need it.

Most importantly, **document well your code**.

Tools like [doxygen](http://doxygen.nl/) could help (perhaps with [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) or [DocBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook)).

Use of course a good enough [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system. I recommend [git](https://git-scm.com/). Also a good [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool.

My suggestion is to publish your C++ code as [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), e.g. on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com). You then could get useful [code reviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) and feedback.

If your hardware + software system is [safety-critical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety-critical_system), consider [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) techniques e.g. with [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or with your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). In a few months (end of 2020), you might try [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (read also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report).

I am definitely biased, but I do recommend trying some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) (e.g. [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) or [Debian](https://debian.org)) as your cross-development platform. Be aware that a lot of devices (including [RaspBerryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/)) are running some [embedded Linux system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_on_embedded_systems), so the learning effort makes sense. Then read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply and references!  I will definitely be looking into them.